# WSDL Response Parsing in Android

Tags: android, parsing, soap, response

How can parse this response in android ;

```
    anyType{
        schema=anyType{
        element=anyType{
        complexType=anyType{
        choice=anyType{
        element=anyType{
        complexType=anyType{
        sequence=anyType{
        element=anyType{}; 
        element=anyType{};  
        element=anyType{}; 
}; }; }; }; }; }; }; 

    diffgram=anyType{
        DocumentElement=anyType{

        PLAKA=anyType{

            ID=7166060; 
            TARIH=2012-07-26T00:00:00+03:00; 
            BOLGEADI=SEVKET TOKUS CADDESI-1; 
            GIRIS=13:39:00; 
            CIKIS=14:41:00; 
            PLAKA=07NSN71; 
            UCRET=1.5; 
            PERON=PERON.1; 
            DAKIKA=62; 
            FIYATADI=3-Normal.01 (1 Saat); 
            BOLGEID=58; 
            SERISIRA=11023; 
            YEDEK_1=anyType{};}; 

PLAKA=anyType{ID=7180277; TARIH=2012-07-27T00:00:00+03:00; BOLGEADI=ATATURK CADDESI; GIRIS=14:22:00; CIKIS=14:57:00; PLAKA=07NSN71; UCRET=1.5; PERON=PERON.1; DAKIKA=35; FIYATADI=3-Normal.01 (1 Saat); BOLGEID=51; SERISIRA=12136; YEDEK_1=anyType{}; }; 

PLAKA=anyType{ID=7305621; TARIH=2012-08-07T00:00:00+03:00; BOLGEADI=ATATURK CADDESI; GIRIS=14:01:00; CIKIS=16:13:00; PLAKA=07NSN71; UCRET=4.5; PERON=PERON.1; DAKIKA=132; FIYATADI=3-Normal.03 (3 Saat); BOLGEID=51; SERISIRA=13471; YEDEK_1=anyType{}; }; 

}; }; }; }
```

I wanna parse this fields;  ID, TARIH, BOLGE ADI, PLAKA for all records... 
I try but i didnt find a solution way.

Comment: Did you find how to parse it?

Answer (score 0):

Normaly, WSDL is used for SOAP requests. This will return you an XML and you need to parse the XML file. For that, I will suggest you the XML Pull parser, it's fast and easy to use. If you can't find how to do it, I can give you an example of how to use XML pull parser.

Comment: @enginar, where from are you getting the data ? Froma a server with soap request right?

Comment: Ok, here is a simple example on how to use the XMLPullParser http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html If there is something you don't understand, please come back to me.

Comment: i try an tutorial but i cant do it :/

Comment: Where are you blocked? Are you using the break points to see if you get some data ? In the link I send you, there is an simple example ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this [website](http://www.wsdl2code.com/Pages/Home.aspx) for creating a package for your web service. Package contain kSoap based classes and classes for parsing responses